# the Keras layers(functions) corresponding to tf.nn.conv2d_transpose

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

In `Keras`, what are the layers(functions) corresponding to `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` in `Tensorflow`?  I once saw the comment that we can `Just use combinations of UpSampling2D and Convolution2D as appropriate`. Is that right?

In the following two examples, they all use this kind of combination.

1) In [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), author builds decoder as follows.

[image]

2) In an [u-uet implementation](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py), author builds deconvolution as follows

```
up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up6)
conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding layers in `Keras` are [Deconvolution2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#deconvolution2d) layers.

It's worth to mention that you should be really careful with them because they sometimes might behave in unexpected way. I strongly advise you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018767/deconvolution2d-layer-in-keras) Stack Overflow question (and its answer) before you start to use this layer.

**UPDATE:**

1. Deconvolution is a layer which was add relatively recently - and maybe this is the reason why people advise you to use `Convolution2D * UpSampling2D`.
2. Because it's relatively new - it may not work correctly in some cases. It also need some experience to use them properly.
3. In fact - from a mathematical point of view - every Deconvolution might be presented as a composition of `Convolution2D` and `UpSampling2D` - so maybe this is the reason why it was mentioned in texts you provided.

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok. I think I found an easy explaination why `Deconvolution2D` might be presented in a form of a composition of `Convolution2D` and `UpSampling2D`. We would use a definition that `Deconvolution2D` is a gradient of some convolution layer. Let's consider three most common cases:

1. The easiest one is a `Convolutional2D` without any pooling. In this case - as it's the linear operation - its gradient is a function itself - so `Convolution2D`.
2. The more tricky one is a gradient of `Convolution2D` with `AveragePooling`. So: `(AveragePooling2D * Convolution2D)' = AveragePooling2D' * Convolution2D'`. But a gradient of `AveragePooling2D = UpSample2D * constant` - so it's also in this case when the preposition is true.
3. The most tricky one is one with `MaxPooling2D`. In this case still `(MaxPooling2D * Convolution2D)' = MaxPooling2D' * Convolution2D'` But `MaxPooling2D' != UpSample2D`. But in this case one can easily find an easy `Convolution2D` which makes `MaxPooling2D' = Convolution2D * UpSample2D` (intuitively - a gradient of `MaxPooling2D` is a zero matrix with only one 1 on its diagonal. As `Convolution2D` might express a matrix operation - it may also represent the injection from a identity matrix to a `MaxPooling2D` gradient). So:
   `(MaxPooling2D * Convolution2D)' = UpSampling2D * Convolution2D * Convolution2D = UpSampling2D * Convolution2D'`.

The final remark is that all parts of the proof have shown that `Deconvolution2D` is a composition of `UpSampling2D` and `Convolution2D` instead of opposite. One can easily proof that every function of a form a composition of `UpSampling2D` and `Convolution2D` might be easily presented in a form of a composition of `UpSampling2D` and `Convolution2D`. So basically - the proof is done :)

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the reply. What confuses me is that in some other cases, there are implementations based on the combination of "upsampling" and "convolution2D) aiming to achieve the similar goal. What are the differences between Deconvolution2D and this combination? I have updated my original post including the mentioned examples.

Comment: Thanks, so can I safely assume that they are mathematically equivalent? Are there any mathmatical derivations for this? Thanks.

Comment: It's rather tedious. I proved it for my self while writing the answer but I couldn't find a written version of this proof. If you really want to - I could write this in a conversation or look longer for a version of this proof in an article.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks a lot for your very detailed answer.